# Moving a div with hotkeys using easing in and out

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on replicating Tagpro using AngularJS and Firebase as a learning project.

I want this ball to move using ease in and out like in the youtube video below.

My code: http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/vCpuf

http://tagpro.koalabeast.com/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyAeDTmG8GI

At least my method goes in the right direction but is super glitchy.

Here is a weird graph of the movement I'm trying to achieve:

[image]